# Boost Test output spamming with "disabled" when running named test

Tags: c++, boost, boost-test

I'm running a Boost Test test/suite by name, using:

```
./MyTestExe --run_test=my_test
```

Unfortunately i'm getting hundreds of:

```
"Test case "bla" is skipped because disabled"
```

But I didn't disable it, I simply chose to not run it.

Is there a way to remove all these messages? However, if possible I would like to keep them for when I run everything and a test is actually disabled?

Comment: Please add a feature request into Boost.Test github project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would have been nice to provide a repro.

So I made the simplest one:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE test module name
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(Suite)
    
    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(A) {
        BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("Yo A");
        BOOST_TEST(1 == 3);
    }

    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(B) {
        BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("Yo B");
        BOOST_TEST(1 == 1);
    }

    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(C) {
        BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("Yo C");
        BOOST_TEST(3 == 3);
    }

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

Which prints **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/524b40f3c24e287d)**

[image]

Now let's run only test case C: `./a.out -t Suite/C`: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d385fbad581ea42)**

[image]

In order to actually see the informational messages you mention, you have to **ask for it**:

`a.out -t Suite/C -l all` **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49a16a0071c0a0c5)**

[image]

The options are:

> ```
>   log_level
>     Specifies the logging level of the test execution.
>     --log_level=<all|success|test_suite|unit_scope|message|warning|error|cpp_exception|system_error|fatal_error|nothing>
>     -l <all|success|test_suite|unit_scope|message|warning|error|cpp_exception|system_error|fatal_error|nothing>
> ```

Turns out you need at leat `unit_scope` or `test_suite` to see it. If you just want to see your own informationals, use `-l message`: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23e86fbbb0959a99)**

[image]

### Conclusion:

Simply do not enable verbose logging.

***Note*** it is possible that the log configuration is made somewhere implicitly. E.g. in a custom runner entry point or read from a configuration file. Also, if this is on some kind of CI server, check your build/CI scripts.

Comment: "Simply do not enable verbose logging."  To be fair to the OP, this is a change to existing behaviour.  My code suddenly started doing this after I upgraded from v1.71 to v1.74.